# Invalid Qualifier When Getting Error Description

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to execute any functions that contain "Err.Description" I receive the error "Compile Error: Invalid Qualifier" and "Err" is highlighted. How can I fix this?

An example of one Sub that has this issue:

```
Private Sub QueryDBIntoListbox(ByRef QueryString As String)
Dim DBPath As String
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ChangeLogDB.accdb"

Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String

On Error GoTo DBError
dbConnection = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & DBPath
db.Open dbConnection
sql = QueryString

'More irrelevant code here

rs.Close
db.Close
GoTo EndSub

DBError:
    MsgBox "An error occurred while executing the query." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Database Query Error" 'ERROR OCCURS HERE
EndSub:
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you used `Err` elsewhere as the name of a variable/procedure/module?

Comment: @Rory That was it... I had an Enum value named that. Easy fix... I'll leave this up in case anyone else has a similar problem. Appreciate the help!